# ffmpegでmovファイルをデコードしたい

Tags: ffmpeg, mov

CentOS7でffmpegを使ってmovファイルをデコードしてmp4ファイルに変換したいと思っています。
以下の通りコマンドを入力しましたがエラーが出て実行できません。
何が原因で対処方法がわかりません。ffmpegのビルドオプションに何かつけなければいけないのでしょうか？

ご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

```
# ffmpeg -i test.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
ffmpeg version n3.1.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
  configuration: --enable-pic --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx265 --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libx264 --enable-ffmpeg --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-libxcb --enable-ffserver
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : hexadecagonal
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
  Duration: 02:07:29.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 63734 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apco / 0x6F637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 45269 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 Proxy
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
[mp4 @ 0x902a40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp4 @ 0x902a40] Could not find tag for codec prores in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apco / 0x6F637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 45269 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 Proxy
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, hexadecagonal (24 bit), 18432 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

またいただいた回答より

```
# ffmpeg -i test.mov test.mp4
```

を実行しました。

```
# ffmpeg -i test.mov test.mp4
ffmpeg version n3.1.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
  configuration: --enable-pic --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx265 --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libx264 --enable-ffmpeg --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-libxcb --enable-ffserver
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : hexadecagonal
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
  Duration: 02:07:29.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 63734 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apco / 0x6F637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 45269 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 Proxy
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0xf56160] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xf56160] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0xf56160] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0xf56160] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[aac @ 0xf56bc0] Unsupported number of channels: 16
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
    Stream #0:0(eng): Unknown: none (libx264), SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0 (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Unknown: none (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-12 09:33:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

という結果でできませんでした。

```
# ffmpeg -i test.mov -ac 2 test.mp4
```

でできるようになりました。

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ffmpeg -i test.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
> ```

上記コマンドは、入力ファイル(MOV形式)から抽出した「映像コーデックを単純コピー」「音声コーデックを単純コピー」し、出力ファイル(MP4形式)に多重化せよという指定です。

> ```
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mov':
>   Duration: 02:07:29.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 63734 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apco / 0x6F637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 45269 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
>     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s (default)
> [mp4 @ 0x902a40] Could not find tag for codec prores in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
> ```

上記メッセージが示すとおり、出力に指定しているMP4メディアコンテナ形式では、映像コーデック prores （Apple ProRes 422 Proxy）をサポートしません。

---

単にMP4形式に変換したいだけであれば、下記コマンドで十分かと思います。この場合、一度prores 映像コーデックからデコード処理が行われ、自動的に H.264 映像コーデックによるエンコード処理が行われます。

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov out.mp4
```

Comment: 実行してみました。結果はできず、状況は質問に追記しました。

Comment: 入力音声が16chもあるため、AACエンコーダが非サポートというエラーになっています。音声トラック(チャネル)の構成が既知であれば、音声Downmixを行うことでエンコード可能です。入力音声の構成はわかるでしょうか？(2ch Stereoや5.1ch surroundなど)

Comment: 入力音声の構成はわかりません。調べる方法などご存知でしょうか？おそらく複数音声は入っているような記憶がありますが。

Comment: 音声データそれ自体から構成を調べる方法はありません。チャネル構成を知っているのはデータ作成者（システム）だけです。一般には、ファイルのメタ情報として格納されたり、システム要件として定義されます。

Comment: 承知しました。チャンネル構成を調べます。なお、2ch Stereoだとどのような指定になりますか？

Comment: 16 channelは扱ったことが無いのですが、運が良ければ`-ac 2`で処理できるかもしれません。上手くいかなければ https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation を参考に頑張ってください。

Comment: -ac 2で処理できるようになりました。